# How to only show a div if a certain entry field is filled in (but not submitted)?

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

Relatively new to html coding, and very new with javascript.  On this page, I don't want the option to email an editor to become visible until a tripID is filled in (but form not submitted yet).  Here is the form so far without that option added yet:

```html
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TripID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='text' id='atripid' name='atripid' size='6' maxlength='6' /><br><br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Port:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='text' id='aport' name='aport' size='6' maxlength='6' /><br><br>

<div id=acheckbox><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;E-mail editor?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
<input type='checkbox' name='acheck' onchange='copyTextValue(this);'/><br>


<div id='div' style='display:none'>

<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Subject:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' id='asubject' name='asubject' size='70' maxlength='75'/><br><br> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name='aemailbody' cols='85' rows = '10'>Explain any packaging or labeling mistakes here...</textarea>

</div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script>

 function copyTextValue(bf) {
        
                if(bf.checked){
        
                        document.getElementById('div').style.display = 'block';
                        var atext = 'Frozen Sample Error Notice: '+ document.getElementById('atripid').value;
                }else{
                        document.getElementById('div').style.display = 'none';
                        var atext = '';
                }
    
                document.getElementById('asubject').value = atext 
                }

  </script>

</div>
```

Now to hide the email editor option until tripid is filled in, I got something like this to work on jfiddle:

```html
<form action="">

  tripid:<input type="atripid" id="atripid" value="">
      
       port:<input type="aport" id="aport" value="">

</form>

<div id="acheckbox" style="display:none">
   <br><br><br>
    This is where the email options (subject and textbox) would appear.
    
</div>
    
    
 <script>
     $("#atripid").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()) {
        $("#acheckbox").show();
    } else {
        $("#acheckbox").hide();
    }
        
});
     
    </script>
```

But for some weird reason, it won't work anywhere else, so I can't figure out how to incorporate it into what I already have.  Does anyone have any ideas that could help me?  Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you are using jquery for the second snippet, have you included jquery in your original code?

Comment: Honestly, I'm such a newbie I didn't realize there was a difference.  Is there a way to do it with javascript?

Comment: add a      `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`      in your html .. preferably between the `<head></head>` tags

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with pure javascript:

```
<input type="atripid" id="atripid" value="" onkeyup="keyupFunction()">
```

And define your keyupFunction().

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sd5s9Lm/)

Answer (score 0):

The code you attempted on jsfiddle requires that you import jquery.js files. An alternate way of doung what you intend to do is

```
<input type='text' id='atripid' name='atripid' size='6' maxlength='6' onkeyup="toggleCheckBox(this)" />

<input type='checkbox' name='acheck' id="acheckbox" style="display:none;" onchange='copyTextValue(this);'/>
```

with js

```
function toggleCheckBox(element) {
    if(element.value=='') {
        document.getElementById('acheckbox').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('acheckbox').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `.keyup()` method, which is not consistent across browsers and does not account for other means of user input.  You would rather, use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) that will detect the `propertychange` of the input field in question and then to fire the desired event if the condition is met.  But for the purposes of simplicity, and the fact that I'm not as well versed enough in IIFE syntax, simply bind some events to the input field, like so:

```js
   $("#atripid").on("keyup change propertychange input paste", (function(e) {
     if ($(this).val() === "") {
       $("#acheckbox").hide();
     } else {
       $("#acheckbox").show();
     }

   }));
```

```css
#acheckbox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">

  tripid:
  <input type="atripid" id="atripid" value="">port:

  <input type="aport" id="aport" value="">

</form>

<div id="acheckbox">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>This is where the email options (subject and textbox) would appear.

</div>
```